# psycopg2 insert statement with LIKE clause containing % sign

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Can't execute a psycopg2 insert query (Postgres db), which uses the best practice %s sign for inserting and contains a LIKE statement which includes a % sign.

% sign in LIKE statement is interpreted as an insert placeholder.

'IndexError: tuple index out of range' is thrown.

Tried escaping % with backslash, didn't work out.

```
with psycopg2.connect(some_url) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        query = """
        SELECT id
        FROM users
        WHERE surname IN %s AND named LIKE '%john'
        """

        cur.execute(query, (tuple(["smith", "mcnamara"]),))
        data = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, actually %s with a collection works fine with me.

Comment: I'm surprised by that, but I attempted an answer below anyway which might help you.

Comment: From the manual: `in order to include a literal % in the query you can use the %% string`.  So, `LIKE '%%john'` should work.

Comment: I know this is old, but the solution above from Jeremy worked for me in this situation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a placeholder also for the `LIKE` expression, and then bind a literal with a wildcard to it:

```
query = """
    SELECT id
    FROM users
    WHERE surname IN %s AND named LIKE %s"""

cur.execute(query, (tuple(["smith", "mcnamara"]), "%John",))
data = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: I had no idea that collections could be bound using statements in Python.  It can't be done AFAIK with Java (which is what I spend most of my time using).

Comment: I can confirm it works in psycopg2 + Python3.x, thanks for the tip Tim.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
with psycopg2.connect(some_url) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        query = """
        SELECT id
        FROM users
        WHERE surname IN %s AND named LIKE '%sjohn'
        """

        cur.execute(query, (tuple(["smith", "mcnamara"]), '%'))
        data = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: You don't need to put single quotes around the `%s` placeholder (in fact, that partially defeats the purpose of using a prepared statement).

Comment: This is just modified initial statement